# How to remove all zeros before the number in a string (and keep the last 0 if it's equals to 0)

Tags: python, logic

**INPUT:** "00012" / "00453403" / "0000000" / "123223"

**OUTPUT:** "12" / "453403" / "0" / "123223"

I can do it in 3 or more lines of code and now I feel dumb because I think there must be a way to do it in one line (lets's say 2 to be safe).

Can someone help to rise the number of beautiful code in the world ? :)

```
    def remove_unnecessary_zero_in_the_beginning(nbr_as_str):
        while len(nbr_as_str) > 1 and nbr_as_str[0] == "0":
            nbr_as_str = nbr_as_str[1:]
        return nbr_as_str
    print(remove_unnecessary_zero_in_the_beginning("00012"))
```

Comment: Can you add a script that shows what you've done? That makes a nice starting point for an answer.

Comment: Here is the most optimized script I made. :)

Comment: Just to highlight why scripts are important, people should test their answers to see if they work with the given input. The original poster should facilitate that with a fully functional test script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str(int(mystring))
```

(too few chars)

Comment: Perfect ! 1 line of code. No library. (even if others could have worked too, I like this design, so pure)

Comment: @Utopion Yeah, actually my first solution was `mystring.lstrip('0') or '0'`, but I liked this one so much better that I didn't bother showing the other one (although for very large numbers it could be significantly faster).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
re.sub("^0+", "", n) or 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression with a match group. This one matches all leading zeros then captures all digits after that. A `\d*?` non-greedy match followed by `\d` ensures that at least the last digit is always present, even if its 0.

```
import re

def remove_unnecessary_zero_in_the_beginning(nbr_as_str):
    return re.match(r"0*(\d*?\d)$", t).group(1)

test = ["00012", "00453403", "0000000", "123223"]
for t in test:
    print(remove_unnecessary_zero_in_the_beginning(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```py
i = ["00012","00453403","0000000","123223"]
o = ["{0:d}".format(int(e)) for e in l]
```

Output:

```py
o
Out[8]: ['12', '453403', '0', '123223']
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a list of the inputs ie : `l1 = [ "00012" , "00453403" , "0000000" , "123223"]`

Code can be :

```
l1 = [ "00012" , "00453403" , "0000000" , "123223"]
test = list(map(lambda x :  x.strip('0') if int(x)!=0 else int(x),l1))
print(test)
```